# Populating a list with DB column names in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I need to populate a list in one of my form using the column names of DB tables. When I pull the filed names from account table the option list will look like the following:

```
<option value="NAME">Account Name</option>
<option value="OWNER">Account Owner</option>
```

In the form list will show like:

```
Account Name 
Account Owner
```

Can I do this using CakePHP functions which will get the column names directly. Or do I need to keep the metadata of the DB tables along with their column description to implemet this.

I am vey new to CakePHP.

Any idea/answer is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can:
A: Set a list from controller action, to use in the view, get a list from the Model::schema() method and "humanize" each value
B: Write a helper method to do it for you

There might be a better way of doing it, but until I find it, let me sing you a song of my AppHelper code:

```
<?php
class AppHelper extends Helper {
 /**
 * Returns and array of 'column_name' => 'Column Name' values from a model
 * 
 * @param string $modelName
 * @param type $includeModelName If true, prepends the model name to the field value
 * @return array Or false if Model is unavailable
 */
function getHumanFieldNames($modelName, $includeModelName = true){
    $model = ClassRegistry::init($modelName, true);
    if (!$model) return false;
    $schema = $model->schema();
    $return = array();
    foreach($schema as $field => $meta){
        $return[$field] = 
            ($includeModelName) ? 
                Inflector::humanize($modelName) . ' ' .Inflector::humanize($field) 
                : Inflector::humanize($field);
    }

    return $return;

}
}
?>
```

Now all your helpers have a getHumanFieldNames method, so to use it in your view, use something like this:

```
<?php 
$accountFieldNames = $this->Form->getHumanFieldNames('account');
// returns array('owner' => 'Account Owner', 'name' => 'Account Name', 'bank_code' => 'Account Bank code')
//you can use any helper instead of $this->Form
//or better yet, you could write your own "utility" helper

echo $this->Form->select('database_column', $accountFieldNames);
// renders a select element with all 
// model column names as values and 
// human readable names as labels
?>
```

I have added a boolean flag as the second parameter, for your convenience:

```
<?php
$this->Form->getHumanFieldNames('account', false);
//returns array('name' => 'Name', 'bank_code' => 'Bank Code')

$this->Form->getHumanFieldNames('account', true); // default is true
//returns array('name' => 'Account Name', 'bank_code' => 'Account Bank Code')
?>
```